# Finding start and end junctions of road from coordinate on road

Tags: pyqgis

I have a list of co-ordinates where traffic counts were carried out.

I wish to associate these traffic counts to the link they are selected with. For that link I want to know the location of its two opposing junctions. For example, on a road that goes north south - I want to know the coordinates of the south junction and the north junction.

If I have a shapefile of points and another shapefile of the road graph (the nodes and links) is there a GIS method for

1. finding the road link that coordinate is on and
2. the coordinates of the closest junctions on that link?

In this case I have a gml file containing the Integrated Transport Network from OS and the traffic count coordinates come from the Department for Transport.

For illustration. Ive used Google maps to plot the coordinates of the traffic count. This is shown as the red flag.

[View post on imgur.com](https://imgur.com/eKFFZc1)

I would then like to find the coordinates of A and B.